# angular : how can i loop in sibling component if the value is coming from other sibling component

Tags: angular

i have a dynamic form that is present in my app component which has a dropdown to select number of tickets and by selecting the value it displays those many number of forms but i have a requirement where i want to display those forms in a different component...so basically i will have select dropdown in one component and the forms in other component

here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-dynamic-reactive-forms-example

Comment: Is both components have parents and a child or sibling ?

Comment: i prefer sibling component rather than parent-child so basically the communication using service

Comment: Please make one service and set and get method. You can use get method in other component.

Comment: yes but that is where im struggling...i already have a incrementer in one component and using a service to get the value in another component but im not sure how to loop it using that value you can see the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060242/how-to-loop-form-in-sibling-component-in-angular